# Image Glitch when refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, image

When I refresh my page, I can see the image glitch.

[image]

#HTML

```
<img id="profileIcon" class="img-circle" src="/assets/be/img/norden/6.JPG?q=0.13941100 1614531096" alt="Forest" style="border: 4px solid rgb(0, 255, 92); cursor: url(&quot;https://i.imgur.com/T2QWx7Z.png&quot;), auto;">
```

How can I avoid that? Should I look into using jQuery animation?
What causes it to glitch? and How can I prevent it? I just want to make a smooth transition refresh.. and hoping that my DOMs are rendering nicely.

Please advise.

## Live Site (please see in mobile)

https://www.bunlongheng.com/norden?code=rithys4k

Comment: It looks like it‘s just loading

Comment: Define 'min-height' to your image element and see the result.

Comment: After adding min-height to 100px. It’s better but the flickering still there ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving border to image directly, wrap `img` tag with `div` and assign `width`, `height` and `border` properties to the `div`.  For the `img` tag, give `max-width:100%`. Give `alt` attribute to show placeholder until the image is loaded.